# Plotting and assigning axes to a PNG-file in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, png

I have several png-files showing some 2d-graphs which I would like to apply axes to. I already know the extent of the files (i.e. x-range and y-range), but do not know how to properly add axes. My current approach is to load the image using

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread('fig_6a.png')
```

which gives me an rgba-matrix. In addition I generate two vectors

```
import numpy as np
x_shape = img.shape[1]
y_shape = img.shape[0]
x_vals = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, x_shape)
y_vals = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, y_shape)
```

create a meshgrid

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_vals, y_vals)
```

and would like to use functions such as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, img) 
plt.show()
```

to create the final picture. Unfortunately, `pcolormesh` does not accept rgba-arrays. What would be the best approach to be able to add these axes to my image, and plot it afterwards?

Comment: can't you not do `plt.imshow(img); plt.grid('on')`?

Comment: In that case I would have to manually assign the different values on the axes, pcolormesh does that automatically, and therefore I'd prefer it

Comment: I don't get it, `plt.imshow(img, extent=(x_min,x_max, y_min,y_max))` seems more efficient than your code. You don't even need to calculate `x_val, y_vals`. Not to mention you would get the correct ratio while `pcolormesh` wouldn't